# How to simulate two coupled birth-death-immigration processes?

Tags: simulation, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, systems-biology

I am simulating a birth-death-immigration process for two coupled populations that interact by virtue of the birth-rate in one population being equal to the death-rate in the other population. The two coupled populations contain the 3 mechanisms births, deaths and immigrations. The birth/death rate mu is dependent on the amount in the population whereas the immigrations rate nu is independent.

[image: rate equation]

The first row is births, second row is deaths and the third row is immigrations.

My thought process on how to simulate these coupled populations is by, if a death occurs, I need to decide which population the death occurs in. I do this by flipping a coin weighted by the sizes of the two populations. I then need to decide whether the death dies out completely or whether it goes into the other population as a birth. A similar thing happens if a birth occurs. I need to decide which population the birth occurs in (using weighted coin), and then determine whether the birth was due to a death in the other population or not. For immigrations I just flip a coin 50/50 to see which population it goes in, since immigrations are independent on the number in the population.

If this is correct, how would I determine if the death/birth in one population was due to a birth/death in the other population?

If my thought process is not correct, how would I got about simulating this type of process?